# Titanium CLI choose iPhone type

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-cli

I'm trying to work with the Titanium CLI (`appc`). This is what I'm running:

```
appc run --platform ios --liveview --target simulator --ios-version 9.3 --sim-type iphone --sim-version 9.3 --skip-js-minify
```

How can I set the specific device to run on (iPhone 4s, 5, 6, 6s, 6s plus ...)? like I choose from Appcelerator Studio?

Also, I'm using Genymotion for Android emulators - I can I use CLI to run on specific emulator?

**EDIT**

I'm running the following command to run on Android Genymotion emulator:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.3.0/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build run --platform android --log-level trace --sdk 5.3.0.GA --project-dir /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MyApp/App --target emulator --android-sdk /Users/ophir/Library/Android/sdk-titanium --device-id Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560 --skip-js-minify --liveview --deploy-type development --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 55633 --config-file /var/folders/4x/8mnrwxd51rb3zmn36p6x30w40000gn/T/build-1466517191446.json --no-banner --project-dir /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MyApp/App
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Invalid "--device-id" value "Samsung"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replicate a studio build, check the console in Studio for the build commmand line that has been generated.

**So for iOS** the key params are :

```
build run --platform ios --target simulator --ios-version 9.3 --device-family iphone --sim-type iphone --sim-version 9.3 --device-id XXXXXXXXXXX
```

you can either cut + paste the UDID of the simulator you are interested in from your studio build, or in Terminal run :

```
xcrun simctl list
```

and pick the UDID of the simulator you want.

**For Android**

```
build run --platform android --target emulator --device-id 'Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920'
```

Get the emulator name by :

```
/Applications/Genymotion\ Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/genyshell -c "devices list"
```

[Genymotion shell docs](https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#start-virtual-devices-command-prompt)

Comment: It doesn't show the command when running from Studio. The first line is "Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.3.0" - which is what you get after running the command.

Comment: Have you set log level to Trace?

Comment: Search for "DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked" and look just below.

Comment: I'm running the exact same command as I see in studio logs and I'm getting the following error: [ERROR] Invalid "--device-id" value "Samsung"

Comment: I've pasted in original question as an edit (too long for here)

Comment: You need to wrap the emulator name in ' quotes or escape the spaces in the name. Like in my example

Comment: --device-id 'TABLET Google Nexus 10 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 2560x1600'

Comment: Ok. Understood my mistake - apparently I've put the wrong ' sign

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can get Titanium to allow me to choose a simulator is by using the following, with two `-`

`ti build -p ios --C`

My Titanium version is 5.0.14

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
ti build -p ios -C ?
```